# Coffee whipped cream filling

Tags: frosting

I want to make a coffee cream filling for a mocha roll cake. If I dissolve instant coffee into heavy cream will it cause cream to not whip up properly?

Answer (score 3):

You should be fine, but you may have difficulties dissolving the instant coffee in cold cream.

Let me suggest a tiny tweak:
Dissolve the instant coffee in a tablespoon or two of boiling water, let it cool until at least room temperature (or even refrigerator temperature) and add it to your semi-whipped cream.

If you use a cream with a sufficiently high fat content - 35% or even 40% - the additional water will not cause any problems with whipping the cream properly. The lower the fat content of your cream or cream-and-other-liquid-mix, the harder it is to whip. Try to stay above 30% and chill your cream and the bowl well. Your heavy cream should be absolutely fine.

Comment: This approach can be improved by dissolving the coffee in hot cream rather than hot water. Heat a small amount of cream, dissolve the coffee in that, cool, add to the rest of the cream.

Answer (score 0):

You'll DEFINITELY be fine without any pre-mixing at all... I've done it and the coffee cream is great !!

Whipping cream is 60+% water, remember ?  There is plenty enough water in the cream alone to dissolve the instant coffee granules...

Whether whipping cream whips up well has more to do with temperature and apparatus, and how much solids are in there... than how many percent fat... As long as it's sold as "whipping cream" it has enough fat to whip up...

Just to allay your fears, Stephie... adding 1 tablespoon of additional water to 1 cup of whipping cream is highly marginal... It's too little to materially affect the fat-water ratio enough to mess up the whipping... just that it's unnecessary...

I use this ratio from Rose Levy Beranbaum :

1 cup whipping cream
2 tablespoons sugar
1 teaspoon instant coffee granules

To the above you can also sprinkle in 1 tablespoon of Dutch-processed cocoa before you whip away... to get a mocha cream, which also tastes delish !!

Comment: I have had mixed results wit using the granules directly. Some brands dissolve, some leave dark specks and a grainy-bitter aftertaste. As for the fat content: US heavy cream is uncritical, in some countries lower fat contents for cream are standard, I have seen as low as 28%. So no "fear", just taking the international character of the site into account: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/64327/what-german-product-is-the-equivalent-of-cream-in-a-recipe-from-the-united-state

Comment: While in that recipe RLB specified Medaglia d'Oro instant espresso powder, I used whatever I had on hand, at least 2 of the instant coffee brands I can recall were from Japan... Never had problem dissolving them in cold cream...   As I mentioned there are so much water inherent in the cream

Comment: Just check one shop I get cream from... 4 brands from France and 1 from New Zealand... MF ranges from 35.0-35.5%... I suppose 28% is on the low side, but if it's sold as whipping cream it should whip fine... If you're that concerned about the additional 1 tablespoon of water, how about taking the same amount of cream and nuke it to warm... and use it as the pre-mixing medium instead ?

Comment: Just because something has high water content doesn't mean it is readily available externally to mix with other ingredients. Cream is an emulsion of the water and the fat so not all of the water content is able to help dissolve the instant coffee. You wouldn't be able to mix instant coffee with "dry water" even though its about 95% liquid water.